# Linq-to-SQL left join on left join/multiple left joins in one Linq-to-SQL statement

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, left-join

I'm trying to rewrite SQL procedure to Linq, it all went well and works fine, as long as it works on small data set. I couldn't really find answer to this anywhere. Thing is, I have 3 joins in the query, 2 are `left joins` and 1 is `inner join`, they all join to each other/like a tree. Below you can see SQL procedure:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM sprawa s (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN strona st (NOLOCK) on s.ident = st.id_sprawy
        INNER JOIN stan_szczegoly ss (NOLOCK) on s.kod_stanu = ss.kod_stanu
        LEFT JOIN broni b (NOLOCK) on b.id_strony = st.ident
```

What I'd like to ask you is a way to translate this to Linq. For now I have this:

```
var queryOne = from s in db.sprawa
               join st in db.strona on s.ident equals st.id_sprawy into tmp1
               from st2 in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join ss in db.stan_szczegoly on s.kod_stanu equals ss.kod_stanu
               join b in db.broni on st2.ident equals b.id_strony into tmp2
               from b2 in tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { };
```

Seems alright, but when checked with SQL Profiler, query that is sent to database looks like that:

```
SELECT ... FROM    [dbo].[sprawa] AS [Extent1] 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[strona] AS [Extent2] 
                ON [Extent1].[ident] = [Extent2].[id_sprawy]    
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[stan_szczegoly] AS [Extent3] 
                ON [Extent1].[kod_stanu] = [Extent3].[kod_stanu]    
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[broni] AS [Extent4] 
                ON ([Extent2].[ident] = [Extent4].[id_strony]) OR 
                (([Extent2].[ident] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[id_strony] IS NULL))
```

As you can see both SQL queries are bit different. Effect is the same, but latter works incomparably slower (less than a second to over 30 minutes). There's also a `union` made, but it shouldn't be the problem. If asked for I'll paste code for it.

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to better the performance of my Linq statement or how to write it in a way that is translated properly.

Comment: If zakreslenie is a variable you could break your statement up in two different statements with an 'if (zakreslenie ==-1) then {} else {}'. OR statements tend to be bad for performance, so it could help. And if you really cannot turn a complex linq statement into a well performing query, perhaps it is worth considering to call a stored procedure instead?

Comment: Badly stored procedure doesn't work really well either. Also, as I said before, problem lies with joins, everything else works fine (tinkered with translated sql query)

Comment: If you cannot make a fast sql query to do what you want, you won't be able to make a fast linq statement either. Optimizing a slq query for speed is a lot easier than optimizing a linq statement though, because with sql you can can get an explain plan to figure out what's slowing it down. It could be the OR in your query that is causing your speed decrease, but it could be a lack of proper indexing as well.

Comment: I already told you where the problem lies, it's how query is being translated, I already tried writing it without 'or', I also had pretty fast SQL query, but it was still too slow on filtering (this one works 6 times faster for small datasets, but gets slower for big ones). I've set indexes on all fields taken from dbo.sprawa which are used in query, on all fields used in joins didn't speed up a tiniest bit.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323547/should-the-order-of-linq-query-clauses-affect-entity-framework-performance In general, in my experience, SQL server many times has bad performance for `OR` clauses. But it seems the Entity Framework designers do not seem to be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of bad OR performance, but it doesn't explain why Linq translates LEFT JOIN in such a strange way or how to make it work faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found the solution:

```
var queryOne = from s in db.sprawa
               join st in db.strona on s.ident equals st.id_sprawy into tmp1
               where tmp1.Any()
               from st2 in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join ss in db.stan_szczegoly on s.kod_stanu equals ss.kod_stanu
               join b in db.broni on st2.ident equals b.id_strony into tmp2
               where tmp2.Any()
               from b2 in tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { };
```

In other words `where table.Any()` after each `into table` statement. It doesn't make translation any better but has sped up execution time from nearly 30minutes(!) to about 5 seconds.

This has to be used carefully though, because it MAY lead to losing some records in result set.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.   If you force tmp1 and tmp2 to have any records to qualify, then you have a join, not a left join.

Comment: Well, it did its job, query works same way and is way faster. I'm not sure, but I think tmp.Any() won't force ANY record to qualify, it'll qualify records which exist. Would you like me to show you result SQL query?