# Should the order of LINQ query clauses affect Entity Framework performance?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework (code first) and finding the order I specify clauses in my LINQ queries is having a huge performance impact, so for example:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var mySize = "medium";
    var myColour = "vermilion";
    var list1 = db.Widgets.Where(x => x.Colour == myColour && x.Size == mySize).ToList();
    var list2 = db.Widgets.Where(x => x.Size == mySize && x.Colour == myColour).ToList();
}
```

Where the (rare) colour clause precedes the (common) size clause it's fast, but the other way round it's orders of magnitude slower. The table has a couple of million rows and the two fields in question are nvarchar(50), so not normalised but they are each indexed. The fields are specified in a code first fashion as follows:

```
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Size { get; set; }
```

Am I really supposed to have to worry about such things in my LINQ queries, I thought that was the database's job?

System specs are:

- Visual Studio 2010
- .NET 4
- EntityFramework 6.0.0-beta1
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Web (64 bit)

### Update:

Right, to any gluttons for punishment the effect can be replicated as below. The issue seems to be tremendously sensitive to a number of factors so please bear with the contrived nature of some of this:

Install EntityFramework 6.0.0-beta1 via nuget, then generate code first style with:

```
public class Widget
{
    [Key]
    public int WidgetId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Size { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}
```

---

Generate the dummy data with the following SQL:

---

```sql
insert into gadget (Size, Colour)
select RND1 + ' is the name is this size' as Size,
RND2 + ' is the name of this colour' as Colour
from (Select top 1000000
CAST(abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 100 as varchar) As RND1,
CAST(abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 10000 as varchar) As RND2
from master..spt_values t1 cross join master..spt_values t2) t3
```

---

Add one index each for Colour and Size, then query with:

---

```sql
string mySize = "99 is the name is this size";
string myColour = "9999 is the name of this colour";
using (var db = new WebDbContext())
{
    var list1= db.Widgets.Where(x => x.Colour == myColour && x.Size == mySize).ToList();
}
using (var db = new WebDbContext())
{
    var list2 = db.Widgets.Where(x => x.Size == mySize && x.Colour == myColour).ToList();
}
```

---

The issue seems connected with the obtuse collection of NULL comparisons in the generated SQL, as below.

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[WidgetId] AS [WidgetId], 
[Extent1].[Size] AS [Size], 
[Extent1].[Colour] AS [Colour]
FROM [dbo].[Widget] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((([Extent1].[Size] = @p__linq__0) 
AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Size] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) 
OR (([Extent1].[Size] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) 
AND ((([Extent1].[Colour] = @p__linq__1) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Colour] IS NULL 
OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[Colour] IS NULL) 
AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',
@p__linq__0=N'99 is the name is this size',
@p__linq__1=N'9999 is the name of this colour'
go
```

---

Changing the equality operator in the LINQ to StartWith() makes the problem go away, as does changing either one of the two fields to be non nullable at the database.

I despair!

### Update 2:

Some assistance for any bounty hunters, the issue can be reproduced on SQL Server 2008 R2 Web (64 bit) in a clean database, as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Widget](
    [WidgetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Size] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Colour] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Widget] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WidgetId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Widget_Size ON dbo.Widget
    (
    Size
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Widget_Colour ON dbo.Widget
    (
    Colour
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


insert into Widget (Size, Colour)
select RND1 + ' is the name is this size' as Size,
RND2 + ' is the name of this colour' as Colour
from (Select top 1000000
CAST(abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 100 as varchar) As RND1,
CAST(abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 10000 as varchar) As RND2
from master..spt_values t1 cross join master..spt_values t2) t3
GO
```

and then compare the relative performance of the following two queries (you may need to adjust the parameter test values in order to get a query which returns a couple of rows in order to observe the effect, i.e. the second query id much slower).

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[WidgetId] AS [WidgetId], 
[Extent1].[Size] AS [Size], 
[Extent1].[Colour] AS [Colour]
FROM [dbo].[Widget] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((([Extent1].[Colour] = @p__linq__0) 
AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Colour] IS NULL 
OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) 
OR (([Extent1].[Colour] IS NULL) 
AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) 
AND ((([Extent1].[Size] = @p__linq__1) 
AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Size] IS NULL 
OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) 
OR (([Extent1].[Size] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))',
N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',
@p__linq__0=N'9999 is the name of this colour',
@p__linq__1=N'99 is the name is this size'
go

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[WidgetId] AS [WidgetId], 
[Extent1].[Size] AS [Size], 
[Extent1].[Colour] AS [Colour]
FROM [dbo].[Widget] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((([Extent1].[Size] = @p__linq__0) 
AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Size] IS NULL 
OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) 
OR (([Extent1].[Size] IS NULL) 
AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) 
AND ((([Extent1].[Colour] = @p__linq__1) 
AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Colour] IS NULL 
OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) 
OR (([Extent1].[Colour] IS NULL) 
AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))',
N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',
@p__linq__0=N'99 is the name is this size',
@p__linq__1=N'9999 is the name of this colour'
```

You may also find, as I do, that if you rerun the dummy data insert so that there are now two million rows, the problem goes away.

Comment: Seems like a terrible choice to use nvarchar for those columns.

Comment: I would think order doesn't affect it at all.

Comment: I expect that the order in the generated SQL is also reversed. Does the order matter if you run a query directly on the database, without Entity Framework?

Comment: Sounds like a SQL indexing issue, maybe?  Is the `Colour` column indexed but `Size` is not?

Comment: I think it depends on how ur records are in database, may be there are only some color records but many sizes available...

Comment: This would only ever be an issue with SQL Server.  That's what would be obligated to optimize the order of the checks to perform the check most likely to filter data first.  That said, it may not be *possible* to do so.  In some cases it could perhaps adjust the order of the checks at runtime based on a given analysis, but I'm not sure if I'd expect it to do that in all cases.

Comment: Check the TSQL coming out.  Examine the query plan.  Typically the query optimizer will find the best but there are cases when the order of the TSQL can affect the query plan but for 2 simple where that surprises me.

Comment: @hvd, if I run my own interpretation of the query (select * from widget where size = 'medium' and street = 'vermilion'), or vice versa, both forms are equally fast

Comment: But what matters is the LINQ interpretation.  Check the TSQL coming out of LINQ.

Comment: @stovroz Could you please post your *actual* code to compare performances? Cause currently it's obviously not the real code (`=` instead of `==`)

Comment: @ken2k, apologies for the typo, corrected now. Apart from renaming the field and table names, that's the actual code.

Comment: @stovroz How did you measure the performance delta? Could you post your test code?

Comment: @stovroz `select * from widget where size = 'medium' and street = 'vermilion'` -- that isn't what gets generated from your LINQ query. Try `select * from widget where size = @size and street = @street` (and the same reversed). If the value is hardcoded in the query in your tests, the query is likely getting optimised for that specific value.

Comment: @hvd, thanks, yes sorry, that would have been a more appropriate translation (indeed the problem goes away when the string literals are hard coded into the linq queries too), but to answer your enquiry, using the parametrised sql is fast in both cases too.

Comment: @ken2k, I've been measuring time with the clock in visual studio before and after the above ToList() operations (the long query is taking long enough to be measurable this way - a few hundred milliseconds)

Comment: @stovroz So you use the same EF context for both performance tests? Remember the EF context caches the loaded entities, so the first query impacts the second one.

Comment: @ken2k, hi again, no the same effect is observed when the two versions are run in complete isolation. I've been trying to put together some more portable code which demos the issue, but it seems to be a product of many factors. I'll update the question when I've got it. I'd be very grateful if you, hvd, or anyone else gets the chance to check back on it tomorrow!

Comment: I cannot repro on SQL12. The plan is almost perfect in both cases. SQL Server filters on the more selective index first, like it should. The order of filter should not matter here because the right index is obvious. Please post the execution plans you are seeing.

Comment: I was able to repro at 100k rows. Thank you very much for the scripts. They allowed me to analyze the problem.

Comment: As far as the bounty is concerned, it's hard to get much more credible than @PaulWhite

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The core of the question is not "why does the order matter with LINQ?". LINQ just translates literally without reordering. The real question is "why do the two SQL queries have different performance?".

I was able to reproduce the problem by only inserting 100k rows. In that case a weakness in the optimizer is being triggered: it does not recognize that it can do a seek on `Colour` due to the complex condition. In the first query the optimizer does recognize the pattern and creates an index seek.

There is no semantic reason why this should be. A seek on an index is possible even when seeking on `NULL`. This is a weakness/bug in the optimizer. Here are the two plans:

[image]

EF tries to be helpful here because it assumes that both the column and the filter variable can be null. In that case it tries to give you a match (which according to C# semantics is the right thing).

I tried undoing that by adding the following filter:

```sql
Colour IS NOT NULL AND @p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL
AND Size IS NOT NULL AND @p__linq__1 IS NOT NULL
```

Hoping that the optimizer now uses that knowledge to simplify the complex EF filter expression. It did not manage to do so. If this had worked the same filter could have been added to the EF query providing an easy fix.

Here are the fixes the I recommend in the order that you should try them:

1. Make the database columns not-null in the database
2. Make the columns not-null in the EF data model hoping that this will prevent EF from creating the complex filter condition
3. Create indexes: `Colour, Size` and/or `Size, Colour`. They also remove them problem.
4. Ensure that the filtering is done in the right order and leave a code comment
5. Try to use `INTERSECT`/`Queryable.Intersect` to combine the filters. This often results in different plan shapes.
6. Create an inline table-valued function that does the filtering. EF can use such a function as part of a bigger query
7. Drop down to raw SQL
8. Use a plan guide to change the plan

All of these are workarounds, not root cause fixes.

In the end I am not happy with both SQL Server and EF here. Both products should be fixed. Alas, they likely won't be and you can't wait for that either.

Here are the index scripts:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Widget_Colour_Size ON dbo.Widget
    (
    Colour, Size
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Widget_Size_Colour ON dbo.Widget
    (
   Size, Colour
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Usr, thanks so much for taking the time to look at this and providing such a great answer. It's just the kind of thing I was hoping for. I'm glad the time I thought I'd wasted grappling with the original problem has led me to a worthy education. I'm late in returning to send the bounty your way and I see that your answer has been graciously augmented by Paul White in the interim. Paul many thanks for your learned contribution, if it's possible award you some further bounty, I intend to do so. Thanks again all.

Answer (score 13):

*Note: I ran into this question long after others have already provided generally correct answers. I decided to post this as a separate answer only because I think the workaround can be helpful, and because you might appreciate having a better insight on the reason EF behaves this way.*

**Short answer:** The best workaround for this issue is to set this flag on your DbContext instance:

```
context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

When you do this all the extra null checks will go away and your queries should perform faster if the were affected by this issue.

**Long answer:** others in this thread are right that in EF6 we have introduced the extra null checking terms by default to compensate for differences between the semantics of null comparisons in the database ([three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)) and standard in-memory null comparisons. The goal of this is to satisfy the following very popular request:

[Incorrect handling of null variables in 'where' clause](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl)

Paul White is also right that the in the following expression the 'AND NOT' part is less common in for compensating for three-valued logic:

```
((x = y) AND NOT (x IS NULL OR y IS NULL)) OR (x IS NULL AND y IS NULL)
```

That extra condition is necessary in the general case to prevent the result from the whole expression to be NULL, e.g. assume that x = 1 and y = NULL. Then

```
(x = y) --> NULL 
(x IS NULL AND y IS NULL) --> false
NULL OR false --> NULL
```

The distinction between NULL and **false** is important in case the comparison expression is negated at a later point in the composition of the query expression, e.g.:

```
NOT (false) --> true 
NOT (NULL) --> NULL
```

It is also true that we could potentially add the smarts to EF to figure out when this extra term is unnecessary (e.g. if we know that the expression isn't negated in the predicate of the query) and to optimize it out of the query.

By the way, we are tracking this issue in the following EF bug at codeplex:

[[Performance] Reduce the expression tree for complex queries in case of C# null comparison semantics](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1598)

Comment: context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true should have been the default not the exception. This causes fairly simple queries to often times ignore indexes and blow up causing deadlocks and timeouts in production environments. Yet another prime example that the programmers at Microsoft just don't get it. You don't abritrarily change the expected default functionality EVER!

Answer (score 3):

Linq-to-SQL will generate the equivalent SQL query for your Linq code. What that means is that it will filter in the same order you specify. It doesn't really have a way to know which will be faster without running it to test.

Either way round, your first filtering will be operating on the whole dataset, and will therefore be slow. However...

- If you filter on the rare condition first, then it can cut the whole table down to a small set of results. Then your second filtering has only a small set to work on, which doesn't take long.
- If you filter on the common condition first, then the set of data left afterwards is still quite large. The second filtering therefore operates on a large set of data, and therefore takes a little longer.

So, rare first means slow + fast, while common first means slow + slow. The only way for Linq-to-SQL to optimise this distinction away for you is to first make a query to check which of the two conditions is rarer, but this means that the generated SQL would either be different each time you ran it (and therefore couldn't be cached to speed it up) or would be significantly more complex than what you wrote in Linq (which the Linq-to-SQL designers didn't want, probably because it could make debugging a nightmare for the user).

There's nothing to stop you from making this optimisation yourself though; add a query beforehand to count and see which of the two filters will produce a smaller result set for the second filter to work on. For small databases, this will be slower in almost every case because you're making a whole extra query, but if your database is big enough and your check query is clever it might end up being faster on average. Also, it might be possible to work out how many there would have to be of condition A for it to be faster regardless of how many condition B objects you have, and then just count condition A, which would help make the check query faster.

Comment: The question has been quite substantially altered since I wrote this about a month ago, but I'm leaving the answer as it is, because it covers some information that may be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

When tuning SQL queries it certainly matters what order you filter your results in.  Why would you expect Linq-to-SQL to never be affected by the order of filtering?

Comment: It is generally assumed that the way you write a query does not affect performance, at least in simple cases, because the optimizer reorders stuff. If you think that is not the case you should elaborate on that. -1

Comment: @usr you said it yourself... "at least in simple cases".. you prove my point by your lack of faith in your statement.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your answer, although correct, does not add any insight into the problem.

Comment: @usr wow... I just scrolled up and looked at the question... when I submitted my answer (almost a month ago) the question was quite different.  I agree that my answer isn't now particularly useful but I disagree with your downvote... just for that I'm upvoting your answer!  +1