# Entity Framework database query very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

In my database there are `Document` and `DocumentFile` tables. Primary key - column `Uid` (in both tables). `DocumentFile` references `Document` via column `DocumentUid`.

I know uid of document file, and I want to select document with files (with left join), and EF generates this query:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__2 varchar(max) ,@p__linq__3 nvarchar(max) ,@p__linq__4 uniqueidentifier

SELECT @p__linq__0=NULL,@p__linq__1=NULL,@p__linq__2=NULL,@p__linq__3=NULL,@p__linq__4='8670AD28-9FA6-41F3-94B9-6B91FD2AE110'

SELECT 
*
FROM  [dbo].[Document] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocumentFile] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Uid] = [Extent2].[DocumentUid]
WHERE ((([Extent1].[EntityUid] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)) OR (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)) 
        AND ((([Extent1].[EntityTypeCode] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[EntityTypeCode] IS NULL OR @p__linq__2 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[EntityTypeCode] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)) OR (@p__linq__3 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__3) AS int)) = 0)) 
        AND ((([Extent2].[Uid] = @p__linq__4) AND ( NOT ([Extent2].[Uid] IS NULL OR @p__linq__4 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent2].[Uid] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__4 IS NULL)) )
```

(long list of columns replaced with asterisk and parameters declared at top, but it does not matter)

This query works very slow with complicated query plan (~20 seconds). If I comment this condition at end of query:

```
 /*OR (([Extent2].[Uid] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__4 IS NULL))*/
```

it run with lightning speed (few milliseconds). Extent2 is DocumentFile, column Uid is primary key and it never be `NULL`.

In C# code column Uid declared as Guid:

```
public class DocumentFile
{
    public const string EntityType = "DocumentFile";

    [Key]
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }

    public Guid DocumentUid { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

How to fix query or tell SQL Server to use simple query plan, like for query with commented condition?

Comment: If you want to select document with files, why are you using an outer join instead of inner?

Comment: In some cases document may be empty, there are no files in document. But i want to select document itself.

Comment: What's your LINQ query? Maybe that can shed some light into why it's generating a null check for a key column. If by any chance the column is defined as nullable in the database (really don't know how/why a key column would be null), maybe you can add the `RequiredAttribute` to `Uid` to tell EF that the column cannot be null, and maybe that way it removes the null check from the generated sql statement.

Comment: RequiredAttribute does not change anything. Linq query is not simple, it modified in some places - added conditionals. I'll edit my post later, if I not find solution.

Comment: I haven't looked at this question in detail but reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18952559/73226

Comment: That is a left join - a null is no match.  If you comment that out do you get the same answer?  You may get the same answer with that data but not all data.

Answer (score 3):

This is because EF by default mimics .net semantics for null values. That is: if a string has a value it never equals null:

```
stringValue != null
```

... evaluates to true.

In SQL semantics this equation is undefined. If used as predicate it *never* yields any result. (Contrary to the correct syntax: `stringValue IS NOT NULL`). Even if `stringValue` is `null`, in SQL, `stringValue = null` doesn't evaluate as true!

You can tell EF to use SQL null semantics, but let's look at a simple example how this can lead to unexpected results. I have a context connected in Linqpad and use this code to compare both semantics:

```cs
string code = null;
this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = false; // the default
Companies.Where(c => c.Code == code).Dump();

this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
Companies.Where(c => c.Code == code).Dump();
```

The first query gives me companies where `Code` is `null`. The second query... none.

The reason for this is apparent from the executed SQL statements:

```sql
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p__linq__0 VarChar(1000) = null
-- EndRegion
SELECT ...
    FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Code] = @p__linq__0)
       OR (([Extent1].[Code] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
GO
```

vs

```sql
SELECT ...
    FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Code] = @p__linq__0
```

There it is, `WHERE [Extent1].[Code] = @p__linq__0` is undefined, the query doesn't return any result.

So you can turn to database null semantics, but that's a decision to be taken with caution. If null values don't play a role (i.e. there will always be comparisons between non-null values), you can do it safely.

Comment: Ok, now I understand this. I'm not not going to enable database null semantics. I changed query to inner join if file uid passed in parameters. If passed only document uid without file uid, I use left join. Seems works fine!