# Retrieving records from Oracle view (in Entity Framework) runs fast with hard-coded string value, but slow with string parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, parameters

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to get read-only access to between 2 and 12 rows at a time. The records are stored in Oracle 11, and accessed via Entity Framework 6, from a view in Oracle. As the title says, it is quick with a hard-coded value, but slow with the string parameter (Example below)
This runs quickly:

```
 public List<VW_COLLISIONS_TS> GetCollisions(string collisionMRN)
 {
       var collisions = (from c in TSP_Context.VW_COLLISIONS_TS
            where c.COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER.Equals("902770479")
                          select c).AsNoTracking();

       return collisions.ToList();
 }
```

But this runs slow:

```
 public List<VW_COLLISIONS_TS> GetCollisions(string collisionMRN)
 {
       var collisions = (from c in TSP_Context.VW_COLLISIONS_TS
            where .COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER.Equals(collisionMRN)
                          select c).AsNoTracking();


       return collisions.ToList();
 }
```

It is taking roughly 30 seconds with the parameter to return the records. Why is this?

**UPDATE: I set up a trace, this is what I got:**

```
[#1 - with hard-coded string value]
Opened connection at 2/9/2017 9:48:29 AM -05:00
SELECT 
"Extent1"."PERSON_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER" AS "PERSON_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER", 
"Extent1"."VEHICLE_MODEL" AS "VEHICLE_MODEL", 
"Extent1"."PERSON_AGE" AS "PERSON_AGE"
FROM "DWOBDEV"."VW_COLLISIONS_TS" "Extent1"
WHERE ('902770479' = "Extent1"."COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER")
-- Executing at 2/9/2017 9:48:29 AM -05:00
-- Completed in 5 ms with result: OracleDataReader
Closed connection at 2/9/2017 9:44:29 AM -05:00

[2. With string parameter]
Opened connection at 2/9/2017 9:44:17 AM -05:00
SELECT 
"Extent1"."PERSON_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER" AS "PERSON_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER", 
"Extent1"."VEHICLE_MODEL" AS "VEHICLE_MODEL", 
"Extent1"."PERSON_AGE" AS "PERSON_AGE"
FROM "DWOBDEV"."VW_COLLISIONS_TS" "Extent1"
WHERE (("Extent1"."COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER" = :p__linq__0) OR (("Extent1"."COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER" IS NULL) AND   (:p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
-- p__linq__0: '902770479' (Type = Object)
-- Executing at 2/9/2017 9:44:17 AM -05:00
-- Completed in 12364 ms with result: OracleDataReader
Closed connection at 2/9/2017 9:48:29 AM -05:00
```

My coworker's take: "I think when you hard-code it is treating as number/integer and when you use string it is treating as varchar/text and then looking for nulls also. Try to use COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER as integer variable, If COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER is of number/int data type."

**What do you guys think?**   [NOTE: Currently, COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER is a varchar2 'number' (no alpha) in the Oracle database]

**UPDATE (Answered!):**
From what Alexander V posted (including the EF link), I came up with this:

```
 var collisions = (from c in TSP_Context.VW_COLLISIONS_TS
                          where c.COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER == (DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(collisionMRN))
                          select c).AsNoTracking();
```

And I added this in the Context constructor:

```
this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

That worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what sql query generates in both cases.

Try add this before .ToList() call:

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)collisions)
            .ToTraceString();
```

If you could post sql queries back, we will see what is going on here.

**UPDATE:** (based on sql query update that @R. Jo posted)

I think performance issue in 2nd query is related to extra NULL checks:
so try to use `== "something"` instead of `.Equals("something")`
because Equals could generate extra null checks for nullable types;
and we EF need to work with 2 different data types here when you doing Equals and we want to avoid that also. (see example below).
If code from example wouldn't work try this'
`UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;` maybe help. 
(see more information here [Why is EF generating SQL queries with unnecessary null-checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433594/why-is-ef-generating-sql-queries-with-unnecessary-null-checks).

**EDIT:**

if COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER then we could do something like

```
public List<VW_COLLISIONS_TS> GetCollisions(string collisionMRN)
 {
       int collision = int.Parse(collisionMRN);
       var collisions = (from c in TSP_Context.VW_COLLISIONS_TS
            where .COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER == collision
                          select c).AsNoTracking();


       return collisions.ToList();
 }
```

Please let me know if it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: I said Oracle 11, it is actually in Oracle 12.

Comment: @R.Jo Along with the generated SQL, please get the execution plan.

Comment: Upon checking this further, most of the running time is spent converting the retrieved data ToList(). Any suggestions?

Comment: More specifically, it's taking about 2-3 seconds to retrieve the data, and about 12 seconds just to convert it to a list!

Comment: I've tried the ToList at several different points in the code after it's retrieved...with similar results.

Comment: I got this attempting the .ToTraceString() : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Core.TSP.Model.VW_COLLISIONS_TS]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

Comment: before you call ToList your query here actually doesn't run yet

Comment: if the way above to get sql query doesn't work for you you could try this: add break point on .ToList() expression and then do watch collisions variable and copy sql expression from there

Comment: @R.Jo I updated the answer based on your sql query traces

Comment: Alexander V, thank you very much! I tried numerous combinations of your suggestions, and what I saw at the link you posted. I'll show what worked in the 'Edit'.