# How to prevent Entity Framework from adding ISNULL checks when joining on a nullable property with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Linq query that is joining on 2 nullable properties.

```
 var result = (from A in context.TableA
             join B in context.TableB
             on A.ExecutionId equals B.ExecutionId
             where B.InsertedBy == userName
```

Both rep.ExecutionId and sch.ExecutionId are nullable int in the database.  What I really want Entity Framework to generate is

```
select 
column1     
from TableA A
inner join TableB B on A.ExecutionId = B.ExecutionId
where B.InsertedBy = @username
```

but what I get is

```
select 
column1
from TableA A
inner join TableB B on A.ExecutionId = B.ExecutionId 
OR ((A.[ExecutionId] IS NULL) AND (B.[ExecutionId] IS NULL))
where B.InsertedBy = @username
```

(Neither one of the ExecutionIds are primary keys). The second query gives me WAY more records than what I need, but more importantly, is not the query that I want.  How can I write the LINQ so that it produces the first query or an equivalent?

Comment: Try `A.ExecutionId.Value equals B.ExecutionId.Value`

Comment: Adding .Value didn't change the generated SQL.  I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: You know that C# evaluates NULL == NULL to true and SQL to false?

Comment: Yes @SirRufo.  I don't want any of the records with null executionids return but I also want to join on that column.

Comment: Then you have to put that into your LINQ statement. Currently you don't

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433594/why-is-ef-generating-sql-queries-with-unnecessary-null-checks answer can help you.

Comment: I wonder what it would produce if you added `A.ExecutionId.HasValue && B.ExecutionId.HasValue` to the `where` clause.

Comment: I tried before posting this question. For some reason that didn't give me the correct results.  I think it may be happening too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want any records where `ExecutionID` is `null`, then use a filter

```
var result = (from A in context.TableA.Where( a => a.ExecutionID != null )
              join B in context.TableB.Where( b => b.ExecutionId != null ) 
              on A.ExecutionId equals B.ExecutionId
              where B.InsertedBy == userName 
              ...`enter code here`
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that you could do that.