# Entity Framework query slow if parameters are passed in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Here is my query which take about ~15 seconds to execute. The table has an index on `REQID`

```
var tls = (from tradelines in _context.TRADELINEs
    where tradelines.REQID == requestId 
    select tradelines).ToList();
```

Model:

```
[StringLength(36)]
[Column(TypeName = "char")]
public string REQID { get; set; }
```

Oracle Db Type for `REQID` is `CHAR(36 BYTE)`

If I execute the same query with hard coded string it return the data in ~1 sec.

```
var tls = (from tradelines in _context.TRADELINEs
    where tradelines.REQID == "2435d403-0beb-416f-a536-0df4e2fcc03f"
    select tradelines).ToList();
```

I have already tried this approach:

```
EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode(requestId)
```

Still no luck. Any idea what I am missing here?

Doing this :

```
[StringLength(36)]
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
public string REQID { get; set; }
```

throws an error saying

> The store type 'varchar' could not be found in the OracleEFProvider
>   provider manifest

Also, there is no change in execution time if I add

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar2")]
```

EF Log Query:

```
SELECT
    // Column List
FROM "TRADELINE" "Extent1"
WHERE (("Extent1"."REQID" = :p__linq__0) OR (("Extent1"."REQID" IS NULL) AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL)))

-- p__linq__0: '2435d403-0beb-416f-a536-0df4e2fcc03f' (Type = Object)
```

I am wondering why it is generating `(Type = Object)` for `string` parameter?

**Now, this is interesting:**

There is another column in same table with following structure,

```
[StringLength(36)]
[Column(TypeName = "char")]
public string ID { get; set; }
```

This column is having primary key with the datatype `CHAR(36 BYTE)`. If I apply the where condition on this column and specify parameter value, it take only few milliseconds to execute. The only difference between `ID` and `REQID` is `REQID` is allow null.

Comment: Try `[Column(TypeName="varchar")]`

Comment: Trace out the EF traffic, or look at the Oracle query plan.  Typically this happens because of a data type mismatch between the parameter and the table causing a table-side conversion.  EF won't  generate a parameter when you use a string literal in LINQ. as @Train suggested, try `varchar` or `varchar2` for the ColumnAttribute.

Comment: If i do `varchar` it gives me an exception and `varchar2` does not improve the performance at all.

Comment: Have you tried setting `UseDatabaseNullSemantics`? See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433594/why-is-ef-generating-sql-queries-with-unnecessary-null-checks

Comment: @Collen : It worked! Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433832/9338546)...

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
    }
}
```