# Set UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true on EF Core Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

With EF 6, It is possible to [remove unnecessary null-checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433594/why-is-ef-generating-sql-queries-with-unnecessary-null-checks) by adding this below:

```
DbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

Is it possible to set UseDatabaseNullSemantics on EF Core 3.1 or is there any other workaround?

Comment: A quick look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics?view=entity-framework-6.2.0 sais `Applies to Entity Framework 6.2.0`

Comment: They did fix it no ? https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17543

Comment: How about `UseRelationalNulls` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaldbcontextoptionsbuilder-2.userelationalnulls?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: @Joel This is the answer, consider converting the comment to an answer.

Comment: @Joel, still adding null check while checking string field with StartsWith.

Comment: @hkutluay Then I guess there's no alternative at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is it possible to set UseDatabaseNullSemantics on EF Core 3.1?*

According to MSDN on [UseDatabaseNullSemantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics?view=entity-framework-6.2.0):

> Applies to **Entity Framework 6.2.0**

Right now it isn't available for **EF Core**. But as mentioned in the comments, it is a requested feature.