# Xamarin.Forms - ListView with SearchBar freezes UI

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, searchbar

I have a ListView and a SearchBar, I use the TextChanged Event of the SearchBar in order to filter the results of the ListView. However every time I enter a value on the SearchBar the UI freezes.

Here's a video with the actual behavior I'm seeing:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SM94AbD_00WDQT9yzpJN8ta_NDj4Lb13

1.- I'm not calling a web service in the TextChanged Event, rather I filter a pre-loaded List in memory. The function takes only milliseconds to return the filtered List.

2.- The ListView uses GroupHeaderTemplate.

3.- The List has around 150 rows.

How can I prevent the UI freezes?

Here's the code:

```
// TextChanged Event

void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

           Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                this.lsProducts.BeginRefresh();

                this.lsProducts.ItemsSource = App.Locator.Products.FilterProducts(e.NewTextValue);

                this.lsProducts.EndRefresh();
           });

}




 // FilterProducts VM function
public List<products_list> FilterProducts(string filter)
{
    List<products_list> theCollection = new List<products_list>();

    if ( ! string.IsNullOrEmpty( filter ) )
    {
        if (_products_list != null)
        {

            List<products_list> entities = (                        
                                            from e in _products_list
                                            where e.Any( x => x.search_field_text.Contains( filter.ToLowerInvariant() ) )
                                            select e
                                           ).ToList<products_list>();



            // if there's entities
            if (entities != null && entities.Any())
            {

                entities.ForEach(x => theCollection.Add(
                    new products_list( 
                            x.products
                            .Where(y => y.search_field_text.Contains( filter.ToLowerInvariant() ) )
                            .ToList() 
                        )
                        {
                            header = x.header
                        }
                    )
                );


            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        theCollection = _products_list;
    }

    return theCollection;
}
```

I can share more details, let me know.

Comment: Your problem is most likely due to the Listview Rendering. How complex is your UI? Are you using CachingStrategy?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro I think you are right, this is the full XAML: https://gist.github.com/LuisDeHaro/b88338268e7b20395132e9410e7f20a3 ...Any help improving the XAML performance will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your UI freezes because of your LINQ query written inside the TextChanged event function. You can reduce the UI freezes by optimizing the LINQ query.

```
var searReqs = yourlist.Where(p => (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Attribute1) && p.Attribute1.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))
```

In the above code, the relevant attributes for the search has been already pre-loaded, which means you do not have to do a SELECT from the list again and can apply the WHERE clause directly. (this clause has been tested for 450 rows with search field)

Let me point out some concerns on your code.
Let's assume that your "**entities**" set returns 100 items, will assume this task is relatively fast. But the "**foreach**" loop you have written is going to be the problem because it has to loop 100 times along with the WHERE clause in the LINQ. This task will be slow down the UI definitely.

I have given some reference to optimize the LINQ query. Have a look at it.

References:

[Should the order of LINQ query clauses affect Entity Framework performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323547/should-the-order-of-linq-query-clauses-affect-entity-framework-performance)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-X

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41273/reduce-or-improve-linq-query-with-nested-from-where-clauses

Entire search code given below for your thought.

```
public void searchData(String serString)
    {
        var searReqs = refList_PettyCash.Where(p => (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Amount) && p.Amount.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower()))
                                                          || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CurApproverFullName) && p.CurApproverFullName.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower()))
                                                          || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CategoryDescription) && p.CategoryDescription.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower()))
                                                          || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Note) && p.Note.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower()))
                                                          || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.RequestCode) && p.RequestCode.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower()))
                                                          || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.RequestedOn) && p.RequestedOn.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower()))
                                                          || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.StatusDesc) && p.StatusDesc.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower()))
                                                          || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Vendor) && p.Vendor.ToLower().Contains(serString.ToLower())))
                                                             .OrderByDescending(p => p.RequestCode)
                                                            .ToList();
        PettyCashRequests = new ObservableRangeCollection<PettyCashRequestsModel>(searReqs);
    }
```

Comment: I removed the ForEach of the code and the UI is still freezing (However the performance improved a little bit, thanks!) https://gist.githubusercontent.com/LuisDeHaro/b88338268e7b20395132e9410e7f20a3/raw/ac95fa593ebea948b51a18da5ee1aa39dae9f509/ProductsViewModel.cs

Answer (score 0):

you are doing Search (longRunningProcess)  on UI Thread. it's gonna freeze ui for 1-2 second.

**solution:**
Move it to another thread via task
or async/await.

Note:
Also its important to eliminate performance mistakes in the code like user:vinoch says.

```
void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
 
 Task.Run(() =>
 {
    // U are in non-ui thread. Do long process here without freezing UI
    var results =  App.Locator.Products.FilterProducts(e.NewTextValue);

    // İ think this is equivalent of winform`s this.invoke(()=>code) . I'll leave it as it is.
    // This code wrapper is to put u back in UI-Tread 
    Xamarin.Forms.Device
.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
    {
     this.lsProducts.BeginRefresh();
     this.lsProducts.ItemsSource = result;
     this.lsProducts.EndRefresh();
    });


 });//--taskRun--end--

}
```

You shouldn't have any freezing right.

İf ui still freezes;

1. it may be about template or
2. image component is not loading in async way